# Multiple stream using android libjingle (WebRTC)

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

When I develop WebRTC Android app using libjingle, I'd like to make multiple stream (ex. one is HD another is VGA) via one camera.
However, I can't find any right solution.
When I tried to make VideoSource as followings, I got RuntimeException.
RuntimeException.

videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer, videoConstraints);

```
06-14 22:55:48.465 13986-15059/com.lgit.webrtc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: EventThread
                                                                 Process: com.lgit.webrtc, PID: 13986
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Capturer can only be taken once!
                                                                     at org.webrtc.VideoCapturer.takeNativeVideoCapturer(VideoCapturer.java:52)
                                                                     at org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(PeerConnectionFactory.java:111)
                                                                     at com.lgit.webrtcclient.WebRtcClient.setTrack(WebRtcClient.java:452)
                                                                     at com.lgit.webrtcclient.WebRtcClient.access$1600(WebRtcClient.java:30)
                                                                     at com.lgit.webrtcclient.WebRtcClient$Peer.<init>(WebRtcClient.java:261)
                                                                     at com.lgit.webrtcclient.WebRtcClient.addPeer(WebRtcClient.java:270)
                                                                     at com.lgit.webrtcclient.WebRtcClient.access$900(WebRtcClient.java:30)
                                                                     at com.lgit.webrtcclient.WebRtcClient$MessageHandler$1.call(WebRtcClient.java:157)
                                                                     at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Socket.onevent(Socket.java:340)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Socket.onpacket(Socket.java:293)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Socket.access$100(Socket.java:19)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Socket$2$2.call(Socket.java:111)
                                                                     at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Manager.ondecoded(Manager.java:407)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Manager.access$1600(Manager.java:20)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Manager$7.call(Manager.java:383)
                                                                     at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                     at io.socket.parser.Parser$Decoder.add(Parser.java:157)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Manager.ondata(Manager.java:399)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Manager.access$1000(Manager.java:20)
                                                                     at io.socket.client.Manager$2.call(Manager.java:350)
                                                                     at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:497)
                                                                     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$900(Socket.java:30)
                                                                     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:299)
                                                                     at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                     at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:127)
                                                                     at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onData(Transport.java:119)
                                                                     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.access$300(WebSocket.java:32)
                                                                     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$1$3.run(WebSocket.java:111)
                                                                     at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: The error doesn't say anything more?

Comment: I got the following message. I can create camera only once and need to use camera frame buffer instead of VideoCapturer.

Comment: Checking the [source code](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-android/blob/master/libjingle_peerconnection/src/main/java/org/webrtc/VideoCapturer.java) I'm afraid you need to look another workaround, because your current aproach won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I need to find another solution as you wrote.

Comment: Is not possible to create two `VideoCapturerAndroid` objects? And with that create two `VideoSource`s. I cannot test it right now

Comment: When I created two VideoCapturerAndroid as you comment, there was "Camera Open Error" in second time.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:551)
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:375)
                                                                           at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.startCaptureOnCameraThread(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:506)

Comment: I don't know then if there is a solution..